# Determine Class Implementation Dynamically via Constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, dynamic, c++17

I want to create a class which behaves a certain way - e.g. spits out certain values from a function `double getValue(const int& x) const` - based on a "type" that was passed into its constructor. Right now I have two methods:

1. Store the passed-in "type" and then evaluate a `switch` statement in `getValue` each time it is called in order to decide which implementation to use.
2. Use a `switch` statement on the passed-in "type" (in the constructor) to create an internal object that represents the desired implementation. So no `switch` required anymore in `getValue` itself.

Method 1 "appears" inefficient as `switch` is called every time I call `getValue`. Method 2 seems somewhat clunky as I need to utilise `<memory>` and it also makes copying/assigning my class non-trivial.

**Are there any other cleaner methods to tackle a problem like this?**

Code Example:

```
#include <memory>

enum class ImplType { Simple1, Simple2 /* more cases */ };

class MyClass1
{
private:
    const ImplType implType;

public:
    MyClass1(const ImplType& implType) : implType(implType) { }

    double getValue(const int& x) const
    {
        switch (implType)
        {
        case ImplType::Simple1: return 1; /* some implemention */
        case ImplType::Simple2: return 2; /* some implemention */
        }
    }
};

class MyClass2
{
private:
    struct Impl { virtual double getValue(const int& x) const = 0; };
    struct ImplSimple1 : Impl { double getValue(const int& x) const override { return 1; /* some implemention */ } };
    struct ImplSimple2 : Impl { double getValue(const int& x) const override { return 2; /* some implemention */ } };

    const std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;

public:
    MyClass2(const ImplType& implType) : impl(std::move(createImplPtr(implType))) { }

    static std::unique_ptr<Impl> createImplPtr(const ImplType& implType)
    { 
        switch (implType)
        {
        case ImplType::Simple1: return std::make_unique<ImplSimple1>();
        case ImplType::Simple2: return std::make_unique<ImplSimple2>();
        }
    }

    double getValue(const int& x) const { return impl->getValue(x); }
};


int main()
{
    MyClass1 my1(ImplType::Simple1);
    MyClass2 my2(ImplType::Simple1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like you want a virtual method (or abstract) and then implement that differently in subclasses

Comment: Does `MyClass2` do what you mean? Basically, I want to avoid having multiple `MyClass`es for each implementation, and have one single point of entry, i.e. the one constructor.

Comment: why do you want to avoid having different classes?

Comment: Say I have 100 different implementations, then I want the user to specify the required implementation via the constructor via an `enum` (simple and straight-forward), as opposed to making the user remember 100 different class names. Additionally, the behaviour of `MyImpl1 impl = MyImpl2();` or `MyImpl10 impl = MyImpl5();` are less clear than `MyImpl impl = MyImpl(Type2);` or `MyImpl impl = MyImpl(Type5);` would be.

Comment: there is no need to remember 100 different class names, knowing the enum is sufficient. Look at my answer

Comment: `MyImpl1 impl = MyImpl2();` what should that do? You want to enable conversions between all different implementations?

Comment: Exactly, it's unclear what it would do. Whereas if I have one top-level type `MyImpl` then `MyImpl impl = MyImpl(Type2);` is clear.

Comment: also if `MyImpl1` and `MyImpl2` are different types a statement like `MyImpl1 impl = MyImpl2();` is completely clear: It wont compile (unless you want to in which case you need to do something extra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically mimicing a virtual method (sloppy speaking: same interface but implementation is chosen at runtime), hence your code can be much cleaner if you actually do use a virtual method:

```
 #include <memory>

 struct base {
     virtual double getValue(const int& x) const = 0;
 };

 struct impl1 : base {
     double getValue(const int& x) { return 1.0; }
 };

 struct impl2 : base {
     double getValue(const int& x) { return 2.0; }
 };
 // ... maybe more...

 enum select { impl1s, impl2s };
 base* make_impl( select s) {
     if (s == impl1s) return new impl1();
     if (s == impl2s) return new impl2();
 }

 int main() {
     std::shared_ptr<base> x{ make_impl(impl1) };
 }
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. By the way, using `<memory>` should not make you feel "clunky", but instead you should feel proud that we have such awesome tools in c++ ;).

EDIT: If you dont want the user to work with (smart-)pointers then wrap the above in just another class:

```
struct foo {
    shared_ptr<base> impl;
    foo( select s) : impl( make_impl(s) ) {}
    double getValue(const int& x) { return impl.getValue(x); }
};
```

now a user can do

```
int main() {
    auto f1 { impl1s };
    auto f2 { impl2s };
    f1.getValue(1);
    f2.getValue(2);
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want `x` to be a pointer `std::shared_ptr` but an actual type?

Comment: what do you mean? `shared_ptr<base>` **is** an "actual type". I have the feeling that you have some wrong prejudice against smart pointers. There is nothing bad about using them

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts, but I basically want to hide the inheritance and abstraction details from the user. Hence I want one class that takes a user input (be it a string or enum) at run-time and then behaves according to what the user input type implied.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX sorry i dont understand what you are trying to say. The inheritance and implementation is hidden from the user. All they need to know is the enum and call `make_impl`, they never need to see the `impl` types

Answer (score 1):

If you have a closed set of types you can choose from, you want `std::variant`:

```
using MyClass = std::variant<MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3, /* ... */>;
```

It doesn't use dynamic allocation - it's basically a type-safe modern alternative to `union`.

Answer (score 0):

More object-oriented approach:

```
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual int getValue() = 0;
};

class GetValueImplementation1 : public Interface
{
    public:
        int getValue() {return 1;}
};

class GetValueImplementation2 : public Interface
{
    public:
        int getValue() {return 2;}
};

class GeneralClass
{
    public:
        GeneralClass(Interface *interface) : interface(interface) {}
        ~GeneralClass() 
        {
            if (interface)
                delete interface;
        }

        int getValue() { return interface->getValue(); }

    private:
        Interface *interface;
};
```

So, in this case you can use it without any pointers:

```
int main()
{
    GeneralClass obj1(new GetValueImplementation1());
    GeneralClass obj2(new GetValueImplementation2());

    cout << obj1.getValue() << " " << obj2.getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
1 2
```

But in the case you should be careful with null pointers or use smart ones inside `GeneralClass`.

Comment: This looks a little like my method 2?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX, it looks like. But the object-oriented approach is more flexible. You have to change a lot of code to add an implementation if you use your `MyClass2`. But with the approach above you just need to create what you want implementing the `Interface` without any changes in `GeneralClass` or other imlementations.